# After installation of Nvidia proprietary driver, when login starts I can hear the Ubuntu startup sound, but screen remains blank

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card, xorg.conf

I installed the nvidia driver directly from the nvidia website. Installation went ok, but after reboot, Ubuntu logo appears fine, but when entering login, I hear Ubuntu startup sound, but the screen keeps black/blank.

Does anyone know what it is? I'm very tired, as long as I tried many things and nothing works.

I'm at a **Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Warhal** box.

Kernel:

```
2.6.38-11-generic-pae
```

NVidia driver module:

> NVIDIA UNIX x86 Kernel Module  280.13

VGA card:

> **GeForce GT540M CUDA**
>
> $ lspci -v | grep -B10 nv
>
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation Device 0df4 (rev
>   a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])     Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc.
>   Device 1642   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16   Memory
>   at db000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]     Memory at c0000000
>   (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit,
>   prefetchable) [size=32M]  I/O ports at d000 [size=128]    Expansion ROM
>   at dc000000 [disabled] [size=512K]    Capabilities:
>
> Kernel driver in use: nvidia
>   Kernel modules: nvidia, nouveau,
>   nvidiafb

Here is my `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Default Layout"
    Screen         "screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "keyboard"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "monitor0"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Modeline "1368x768_60.10"  86.00  1368 1440 1584 1800  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "card0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection


Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "screen0"
    Device         "card0"
    Monitor        "monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "DFP"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes      "1366x768_60.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I cant see any errors on my [Xorg.0.log](http://pastebin.com/raw.PHP?I=46npVWp8) file.

Also on my blacklist:

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf 
# generated by nvidia-installer
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

Worth to note that I have an Intel onboard video card installed apart from the dedicated nvidia one.

Any insights?

Comment: Question - have you tried plugging a monitor into the intel devices output? ALthough your Xorg.conf does not configure it, your Xorg.log seems to show this was the one used.

Comment: Yes, i have already tried and it indeed works. But my goal is to make my nvidia card work with Ubuntu. It's kinda disappointing to have a good card, and are unable to use it.

Comment: The log doesn't actually show the nvidia driver being loaded - it has already started on the internal card - hence a blank output on the other. Are you sure the xorg conf is even being read/used?

Comment: You are right. I think that log is pasted wrong (I was changing things all over from time to time...). Sorry for that. Actually, I think I found an answer, which is not exactly good... I will post an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will post an answer to my question, so that it stays more visible to anyone who are interested.

Fact is, my laptop has a hybrid VGA configurations (nvidia and intel), and seems that there is still not a support for hybrid linux systems from nvidia. It's something related to [nVidia Optimus Technology](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html).

What I could understand so far is that it works this way: the desktop launches and is supported by the low-end Intel card. Also the monitor is attached to intel. So far ok, until some app demands 3D acceleration. In case when nVidia card is requested. What would normally happens is that the framebuffer on nVidia is copied to intels and then shown on monitor's display.
On linux though, this mechanism fails and the cards cant work together, so the screen gets blank.

There is a partial workaround, called Bumblebee. Please follow this [link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/bumbleebee-brings-nvidia-optimus-gpu-switching-to-linux-users/).

Comment: users are encouraged to post solutions to their own question ,you can even mark it as accepted answer if you find it the most fitting of all the acceptable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `gksu nvidia-settings` - this should configure your nvidia card, generate the configuration and ensure Xorg uses it.