# How to reset the graphics drivers in Linux Mint back to the open source version?

Tags: drivers, linux-mint, nvidia-graphics-card, cinnamon

### Introduction

I have a Dell XPS 15 7590 laptop, and have managed to break the desktop video drivers in Mint 20 Cinnamon. (Background: my system was working with a Thunderbolt/USB 3-C connection to a Dell monitor, but now I have an Apple monitor I want to use as well, which only offers Mini-DVI, so I wanted to get the first monitor to work with HDMI. This did not do anything when using an HDMI cable).

To see if I could get HMDI working with the first display, I went into Driver Manager, and changed from video-nouveau to nvidia-driver-xxx, and unfortunately the progress bar kept on cycling through progress states without settling. Perhaps rather foolishly I rebooted at this point, and now I can't boot from the login screen to the desktop.

### What I have tried

Of course, that means I cannot now access the GUI version of Driver Manager in order to try to set it back. I followed some of the [advice here](https://itsfoss.com/nvidia-linux-mint/) to try reconfiguring the Driver Manager by hand, via the recovery console, but it seemed to make matters worse. I also tried `nvidia-xconfig`, which rewrote my `xorg.conf`, and for a while it would not even boot to the login screen.

I used [this Superuser post](https://superuser.com/a/1622916) to rescue things:

```
root@xps15:~# sudo apt purge *nvidia*
```

I can now get back to the login screen, but if I try to login, it accepts the password, fails to get a working video driver, then comes back to the GUI login prompt.

I have also tried running a prior kernel from the Advanced menu in Grub. This did seem to make a slight visual difference to the disk decryption page, but I don't think it is relevant.

### More info

The instructions that seemed to make things work did help in another fashion though - it listed some commands that may yet still help. For example I think the Nvidia driver is still in force even though I thought I had purged it:

```
root@xps15:~# nvidia-detector
nvidia-driver-465
```

I can also list the available devices (transcribed by hand into another laptop, I can't copy+paste at present):

```
root@xps15:~# ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/.. ==
modalias: pci:...
vendor  : NVIDIA Corporation
model   : TU117M ...
driver  : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver  : nvidia-driver-465 - distro non-free
driver  : nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free recommended
driver  : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver  : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver  : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro built in
```

I can also list the drivers available (again, imperfectly transcribed):

```
root@xps15:~# ubuntu-drivers list
nvidia-driver-418-server
nvidia-driver-450-server
nvidia-driver-460
nvidia-driver-465
nvidia-driver-460-server
```

Unfortunately if I try `nvidia-driver install nvidia-driver-460` then it gives an error:

```
root@xps15:~# nvidia-driver install nvidia-driver-460
No drivers found for installation.
```

I think this is an unfortunate side-effect of the `purge` previously.

I have also tried reinstalling this:

```
root@xps15:~# apt install nvidia-driver-460
{ fetches & installs }
root@xps15:~# nvidia-driver install nvidia-driver-460
No drivers found for installation.
```

I discover from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/340537) that `nvidia-settings` might help be successfully press forward with an Nvidia driver (perhaps that is easier than going back to the open source one). However it does not work in the console:

```
root@xps15:~# nvidia-settings
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run `nvidia-settings --help` for usage information.
```

I am not optimistic that trying to reinstall Nvidia has helped, so I have purged the drivers again.

I furthermore noticed errors in the resulting `apt-get` output regarding problems with `plymouth-themes` and `plymouth-label`. I don't know what they are, but installing them has helped fix the minor font problems on the disk decryption screen. However, the desktop will *still* not start up.

### Status

The computer is operational - the drive is healthy, it decrypts fine, I can reliably get a recovery prompt, and I can run console commands and edit config files manually. I can also get a network connection via Ethernet.

### Questions

- What can I try next to rescue this?
- I can access log files, but there are some ~20 that appear to have very recent timestamps at boot time. It is thus difficult to work out which one contains the relevant failure information. Which one would be likely to assist me?

### Resources

- [Linux Mint Nvidia Graphics driver issues](https://superuser.com/questions/1591573/linux-mint-nvidia-graphics-driver-issues) - unanswered
- [After installation of Nvidia proprietary driver, when login starts I can hear the Ubuntu startup sound, but screen remains blank](https://superuser.com/questions/339713/after-installation-of-nvidia-proprietary-driver-when-login-starts-i-can-hear-th) - I think this is a false lead. This one recommends a GPU switching solution. I merely want to go back to the F/OSS driver, which should fix things. I am very hesitant to try anything further with Nvidia drivers, and I don't want to risk my essential laptop with more experimentation than is necessary.

Comment: In the small hours of this morning, I seem to have got a breakthrough - in recovery mode, getting access to the encrypted home folder [via this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/679565) seems to fix it. In fact I broke it a second time about an hour ago, and this fix worked again. No idea why.